# Laptop not working after suspend 14.04 lts

Tags: 14.04, suspend, hp

Whenever I put my laptop (HP Pavilion: g6-2051SD : amd a10 4600, 6 gb dd3 ram) in suspend state and try to resume, nothing happens.

The fan does start blowing but the screen stays black/blank no matter what I do.

Answer (score 1):

I switched to the AMD driver and the suspend problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i've got this problem. As a work round, go into settings and change the power management setting for closing the laptop lid to do nothing. I believe the solution is  outside the scope of this list and needs to be reported to bugzilla.

Comment: Just checked my setup, you also need to change the other settings to something reasonable.